# how to insert data to a mysql table using ajax (client side)

Tags: mysql, ajax, insert, client

the client generates the data that should be stored in the database. I like to use ajax to save the data. can you please help me?

I have used the following code in a JS file:

```
var queryString = "?hrefAdd=" + hrefAdd;
ajaxRequest.open("GET","ajax_request.php" ,queryString , true);
```

and this is the ajax_request.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "1admin") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("lln") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE links(

link_add varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (link_add))")
or die(mysql_error());  
$link = $_GET['hrefAdd'];
// Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
 $link = mysql_real_escape_string($link);
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO links (link_add) VALUES ('$link')") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

but nothing is inserted in the table.

Comment: You need to do this server-side. Are you familiar with a server-side scripting language like php?

Comment: client generates the data. What it means ? who pulling data. is it form submit ?

Comment: can you please see the post updates

Comment: Any idea where it's failing? Can you echo your query out to a page then try executing that query directly on the table?

Comment: queryString is ok. I even checked with $link = "hello"; but nothing is stored in the table.

Comment: nasi, You don't seem to understand basic SQL/ajax/etc.  For example, you are creating a table every time the ajax occurs?! Honestly, you should get back to learning the basics..  People here might be able to get you a short term answer but if you're this clueless to how things work, you won't even understand what you're doing.

Comment: @nasi - what do you mean queryString is ok? does the insertion happen if you run the query directly on the table? if it fails there, then it's not ok - if it doesn't fail there, then we need to have some idea where your program is failing - and like babonk states, you shouldn't create your table every time your script runs.

Comment: @ babnok this is just a siplified code. I delete the table before running the ajax_request.

Comment: @ user156629 as I said this is just a siplified version of the code. querystring is what is generated in the js file and it is what it should be. mysql_query("INSERT INTO links (link_add) VALUES ('hello')") works but. I think there is something wrong with ('$_POST[link]') in this line.

Comment: huh? I don't see ('$_POST[link]') anywhere in the code you've shown us. It's going to be impossible to help you if you don't give us an idea of where the failure is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this using jQuery's [ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) combined with a server side scripting language like PHP.

You would have a file, e.g. ajax.php, which will be POSTed to from the client using the jQuery ajax function.

If you are not familiar with the basic of AJAX and/or scripting languages, you should begin by reading some introductory articles and documentation.

Update: Based on your code, you really need to get back to learning the basics before anyone can help you here.  You try to create a tbale every time the AJAX occurs?!  Also, you just copy-pasted a javascript ajax line you saw somewhere without any context.. Of course it won't work.  Please get back to learning the fundamentals before you try coding it..

Comment: I don't know why people don't know your answer, or don't underestand your question keep on telling you that you don't know what you are doing??!! this is just a simplifed code. I delete the table before runing it. but my problem was very sipmle. It was just a kind of syntax error in ajaxRequest.open "GET","ajax_request.php" ,queryString , true); I had use , instead of + before 'queryString'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use server side code to store data in a database. Howerver you can use Ajax to send your data from a client to server and get it stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

@nasi You can use PHP AJAX here to store the data which is given by user at client side. Following link shows how data is fetched from server side ..look at this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

you can easily understand.Try to use insert query for your requirement.

Comment: thanks for the link but it is about getting data from the dataase not iserting data to database!

Comment: @nasi yes,here you have to get the data given in input box and pass it to another file having DB stuff to store the data using AJAX. Look at the link to insert data in DB using PHP http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp . Try to combine all these stuff to complete your requirement.

Comment: queryString is ok. I even checked with $link = "hello"; but nothing is stored in the table.

Comment: @nasi First You are about to create TABLE every time you call ajax_request.php and try to use that query string in your sql manually.

Comment: I detele the table before I run the ajax-request manually. query String is a bit complicated, I can't make it manually. for simplicity I used $link="hello" in ajax_request. but it is not inserted in to the table.

Comment: @nasi If you deleted the table which you want to store the data, then how and where the date could stored? Try to create Table manually and then use INSERT stuff in your code. I hope you understand

Comment: I think there is something wrong with ('$_POST[link]') in the line: mysql_query("INSERT INTO links (link_add) VALUES ('$_POST[link]')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @nasi First do the echo $link = $_GET['hrefAdd']; and then check the passed value and echo the query and try to use the echoed QUERY in SQL directly not doing run the code. Check what happens ?

Comment: it was a stupid mistake.  I had used  , instead of + before 'queryString' in ajaxRequest.open ("GET","ajax_request.php" ,queryString , true);